# Correctly understanding relations

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I get that something such as `R={(0, 0),(0, 1),(1, 1),(1, 2),(0, 2),(2, 2)}` on the set `{0, 1, 2}` would be reflexive, anti-symmetric, transitive and a total ordering, however things that are less cut and dry such as:

Suppose that F is a set of files, and R is the relation on F where `fRg` if g depends on f. That is, f must come before g. Noting that the dependency may not be direct - g might depend on f through some intermediary files such as h or j.

I can tell that it is transitive (based on last part of question), that is `fRh ∧ hRg → fRg`, but am unsure how to prove whether or not R is reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, partial ordering or total ordering (strict or not) and the equivalence class.

How would I go about identifying these?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is it possible for $f$ to depend on $g$ and simultaneously $g$ to depend on $f$ (for $f\ne g$)? Is it possible for a file $f$ to depend on itself?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I do not believe fRf is valid and that f≠g, and so if gRf is not valid and only fRg is, then it cannot cannot be symmetric, making it anti-symmetric, I don't think elements relate to themselves (I assume based on f≠g, not sure how to prove/ if correct), thus is irreflexive, making this irreflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive, which is a _strict_ partial ordering correct?

Comment: Sounds good to me. You could write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so because f≠g, fRf is invalid, this all creates a strict partial ordering, but how would I go about showing whether or not it is actually a strict total ordering or not? I know to be a total ordering it must first suffice partial ordering.

Comment: but not sure about the comparability condition or what it would be in this instance, usually its a greater than or similar of the previous using the Trichotomy Law. However, I'm not sure in this instance whether or not it can be done

Comment: If you can have two files such that neither one depends on the other, then you don't have trichotomy, you don't have a total order.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so because **g depends on f** either directly or indirectly, so it is an example of total ordering then?

Comment: If you can have two files such that neither one depends, directly or indirectly, on the other, then you don't have a total order.

Comment: If you have, as in that example, jRl, lRq, and qRj, then you are saying j must come before l, l must come before q, and q must come before j. Is it possible for files to behave that way? If so, then transitivity would imply jRj, which I thought you had ruled out.